# QGIS 'Difference' tool return empty layers

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, qgis-2.10, differences

I've been using QGIS's difference tool to create some new layers. All was going well until I hit a number of layers which return a blank layer with no features when I use the difference tool.

The shapefiles for the input and difference layers can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bd43bd3mtbsxu9r/AABW5RWlZn9iXiMYorD8Xftra?dl=0

QGIS 2.10.1 - Pisa running on OSX 10.10.5

Comment: At least the input_layer has ring self-intersection at POINT (    39.21075154537676 -6.883819577332873). Try if fixing it would help. OpenJUMP is computing differences even without fixing source data at least for couple of the first layers which I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user30184 mentioned, there are errors in your "input_layer". You can use the GRASS tool **v.clean** to clean most of the errors. Use the **break** option with a threshold of **0.1**. This should 'break' your single polygon into multiple polygons (you can uncheck the *Errors* output as you don't really need this):

[image: v.clean]

[image: Cleaned input_layer]

If you want, could **dissolve** this based on an attribute field (doesn't matter which, all values are the same). I also found it easier to **merge** all your "difference_layers" using *Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Shapefiles to One*:

[image: Merged difference_layers]

Finally, you should be able to run the **difference** tool now using your newly cleaned and merged layers:

[image: Difference tool]

[image: Difference result]

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANKS!!! Incredibly helpful. All working perfectly now!

Comment: @usabledata - Awesome buddy! Glad it worked :)

Comment: I can't figure out how to get my QGIS layers into a GRASS mapfile to run v.clean on them...

Comment: @Baodad - Run QGIS with GRASS, either create or open an existing mapset, use `v.in.ogr.qgis` or `v.in.ogr` to import a vector layer. You can then run `v.clean` on the newly imported GRASS layer :)