# Inverting shapefile in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: pyqgis, convert, geoprocessing, qgis-2, vector-layer

I asked a question earlier about how to invert my file `"hydropolys.shp"` from a vector of ocean and seas to a vector of land and got sent to [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187215/inverting-polygons-using-qgis), but I am experiencing issues where using the "Difference" tool, it returns an empty map.

So I tried to follow the instructions [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170733/qgis-difference-tool-return-empty-layers) but this tool keeps giving the `"Not Responding"` error. Any suggestions on what to do next? Or any other easy way to convert the shapefile? I am using QGIS 2.18. Or is there a way to do this instead in code in PyQGIS?

Comment: You can additionally check this article [QGIS 'Difference' tool return empty layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170733/qgis-difference-tool-return-empty-layers) and as was mentioned by @Joseph, you may apply [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html).

Comment: did you make sure your features are of the same coordinate system?

Comment: In my question I mentioned that I tried the v.clean tool given from that link, but it is not working @Taras

Comment: Shouldn't the features be of the same system, since I am just creating a new extent layer from my hydropolys layer and then trying to get the difference?

Comment: If you've got the chance to upgrade then this tool is MUCH improved in 3.x